# Microsoft VS Code on Mac OSX: doesn't appear in OSX (top of screen) menubar

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I'm running Microsoft VS Code on Mac OSX 10.11.6. VS Code doesn't appear in the main OS X menubar at the top of the screen. None of the menu functions are directly available. I have  "window.menuBarVisibility": "default" in settings.json.

Added: I noticed that the menubar "flashes" on launch. When the app is launched, the menubar briefly shows a "Code" menu as desired, but it's quickly replaced by the "Finder" menu.

Renaming the app and/or deleting the app and reinstalling don't help.

I was able to download a copy of VS Code from a different machine which worked briefly, until VS Code self-updated. Since the update, the menubar problem seems permanent.